# FileNet IDM View Control 3.3

Tags: filenet, filenet-panagon

Question about a rather old technology, guess that is why web search has not helped me.

I am using `FileNET Panagon IDM Viewer Control 3.3,` part of IBM `FileNet IDM Desktop 3.3` on my web page for the user to view TIFF files. They have ability to annotate the file using this control.

While I am trying to use annotation, I get an error which says that the annotations are not supported. The JS call on the object of this control `FnViewCtrl.IsOperationSupported(i)` returns `false`.

This is working fine on a few other servers where this web application is hosted.

Not sure if its issue with installation of IDM or some settings somewhere.

Crossing my fingers, hope we have some folks on the forum who are expert in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You said "on your web page"... Custom web page? The Tiff documents can be opened in one of two ways, "view" or "open". In view mode the viewer can communicate back to the server to update the annotations, in 'open' mode it does not. Annotations are not stored in the Tiff header, they are stored in the database. For this to work then there is a lot of underlying 'infrastructure' in the out of box code that handles the backend communication. Hosting the viewer control in a page outside of IDM Web/Open Client without that won't work. You didn't say, but there are minor differences between the controls supplied with  IDM Web and those that come with IDM Desktop.